# Joining two tables with many columns but that gives many duplicate result in sql

Tags: sql

I am using this query for the joining the table pls give me proper solution
there are 600 Rows and its gives 1938 results.

```
select 
    b.FValue as title, k.FValue as subtitle, c.FValue as isbn, 
    d.FValue as issn, E.FValue as Author, f.FValue as roleofauthor, 
    g.FValue as editor, 
    h.FValue as publisher, i.FValue as publisherPlace, 
    j.FValue as pyhsicaldescription, m.FValue as Subject , 
    n.FValue as Note , l.p852 as AccessionNo, 
    l.DateofAcq as AccessionDate,
    l.a852 as location,l.Budget as Budget, l.k852 as ClassNo, 
    l.m852 as bookNo, l.Price as Price, l.t852 as CopyNo,
    l.Supplier as supplier, l.b852 as collectionttype,
    l.Material As materials, l.status 
from 
    Biblidetails b
left join 
    Biblidetails c on b.RecID = c.RecID and c.Tag = 020 and c.SbFld = 'a' 
left join 
    Biblidetails d on b.RecID = d.RecID and d.tag = 022 and d.SbFld = 'a' 
left join 
    Biblidetails e on b.RecID = e.RecID and e.Tag = 100 and e.SbFld = 'a' 
left join 
    Biblidetails f on b.RecID = f.RecID and f.Tag = 100 and f.SbFld = 'e' 
left join 
    Biblidetails g on b.RecID = g.RecID and g.Tag = 250 and g.SbFld = 'a'
left join 
    Biblidetails h on b.RecID = h.RecID and h.Tag = 260 and h.SbFld = 'b'
left join 
    Biblidetails i on b.RecID = i.RecID and i.Tag = 260 and i.SbFld = 'a'
left join 
    Biblidetails j on b.RecID = j.RecID and j.Tag = 300 and j.SbFld = 'a' 
left join 
    Biblidetails k on b.RecID = k.RecID and k.Tag = 245 and k.SbFld = 'b' 
left join 
    Biblidetails m on b.RecID = m.RecID and m.Tag like '6%' and m.SbFld = 'a'
left join 
    Biblidetails n on b.RecID = n.RecID and n.tag like '5%' and n.SbFld = 'a'
left join 
    location l on b.RecID = l.RecID where b.Tag = 245 and b.SbFld = 'a'
```

Comment: Using multiple `LEFT JOIN`s can cause some ties ;).

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a group by on the RecID. Try

```
select b.FValue as title, k.FValue as subtitle, c.FValue as isbn, d.FValue as issn,E.FValue as Author, f.FValue as roleofauthor, g.FValue as editor, 
h.FValue as publisher, i.FValue as publisherPlace, j.FValue as pyhsicaldescription, m.FValue as Subject , 
n.FValue as Note , l.p852 as AccessionNo, l.DateofAcq as AccessionDate,
l.a852 as location,l.Budget as Budget, l.k852 as ClassNo, l.m852 as bookNo ,l.Price as Price,l.t852 as CopyNo,l.Supplier as supplier ,
l.b852 as collectionttype,l.Material As materials,l.status from Biblidetails 
b left join Biblidetails c on b.RecID = c.RecID and c.Tag = 020 and c.SbFld = 'a' 
left join Biblidetails d on b.RecID = d.RecID and d.tag = 022 and d.SbFld = 'a' 
left join Biblidetails e on b.RecID = e.RecID and e.Tag = 100 and e.SbFld = 'a' 
left join Biblidetails f on b.RecID = f.RecID and f.Tag = 100 and f.SbFld = 'e' 
left join Biblidetails g on b.RecID = g.RecID and g.Tag = 250 and g.SbFld = 'a'
left join Biblidetails h on b.RecID = h.RecID and h.Tag = 260 and h.SbFld = 'b'
left join Biblidetails i on b.RecID = i.RecID and i.Tag = 260 and i.SbFld = 'a'
left join Biblidetails j on b.RecID = j.RecID and j.Tag = 300 and j.SbFld = 'a' 
left join Biblidetails k on b.RecID = k.RecID and k.Tag = 245 and k.SbFld = 'b' 
left join Biblidetails m on b.RecID = m.RecID and m.Tag like '6%' and m.SbFld = 'a'
left join Biblidetails n on b.RecID = n.RecID and n.tag like '5%' and n.SbFld = 'a'
left join location l 
on b.RecID = l.RecID where b.Tag = 245 and b.SbFld = 'a'
GROUP BY b.RecID;
```

Comment: an error  is = "Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Column 'Biblidetails.FValue' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."